# How to properly setup script to work with XML api end point also be able to receive and send data?

Tags: python, xml, python-requests, api-design

As the title suggests, I need some help in setting up a script that will extract data from an API, using python 2.7. The API in question for a platform by the name YourMembership, documentation here (https://api.yourmembership.com/reference/API_Getting_Started.pdf#view=Fit).

My hangup is that I have always used pre-existing scripts to communicate with API's and do not know how to setup the script that will make the call from scratch. Second hangup is that I have never used XML to communicate with an API, so not sure how to send the message to get data.

In my research I know that I have to use the 'requests' library with Python, and this is the few lines I have setup so far, with status_code= 200.

```
import requests

url = 'https://api.yourmembership.com'

api_key_public = 'xxx-xxxx-xxxx'
api_key_private = 'xxx-xxx-xxxx'

r = requests.get(url, api_key_private)
print(r.status_code)
```

What am I doing wrong? because I know that my API keys are not being inputted, and how do I submit a command in XML through my script?

Thank you in advance.

Edit:

I am currently working with this script getting the error that my XML is mis-formed, but in a XML validator all checks out. What could I be doing wrong?

```
import requests

xml = """
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<YourMembership>
    <Version>1.62</Version>
    <ApiKey>xxx-xxx-xxx</ApiKey>
    <CallID>001</CallID>
    <SaPasscode>xxxxx</SaPasscode>
    <Call Method =Sa.Events.All.GetIDs" >
    </Call>
</YourMembership>


"""

print(requests.post('https://api.yourmembership.com', data=xml).text)
```

**Edit**
Do I need headers?

Comment: Did you leave out the values for the `Version` and `CallId` fields on purpose?

Comment: Hi @etemple1 I did not leave them out on purpose, just forgot to put in values. Will edit it in.

Comment: Sorry, my question wasn't clear. Did you leave out the values when you made the request? As per your question about headers, do the docs for this particular API mention including headers?

Comment: In the request all fields are filled, and I am not exactly sure how to interpret this from the documentation regarding headers, as I do not know what to add in the script:

Comment: documentation about headers:

Q: Should I use a specific content type and character set when making method calls?
A: Yes. For most method calls, the content type (Content-Type) header must be set to
application/x-www-form-urlencoded and the recommended character set is UTF-8. However,
for specific methods that require a file or files to be sent along with the request, the content
type must be multipart/form-data to enable transmission of the uploaded file. Also note that in
this situation the XML data should be sent over in a form field named XmlMessage.

Comment: Ah, ok. So you should create a header dict to include in your request. Something like `headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}`, and add it as an argument in the request method `headers=header`.

Comment: @etemple1 Thank you so much! finally got it too work! will approve

Answer (score 0):

As @etemple1 suggested, need to add in headers.